find a file name using command line
I would like to determine the location of a file using command-line. I have tried:
find ./tor.keyring
I must be missing something here

Have you done any basic reading before posting on how to use the find command? You'll hopefully be able to work out exactly what you need with the output of man find command

... see for example One-word command to search for a file

sudo find / -name tor.keyring 

this will search the whole system.Depending on the amount of files this can take a while (locate tor.keyring might then be a better method).
sudo find "$HOME" -name tor.keyring

this will search your home.
sudo find . -name tor.keyring

will search from the current directory.
sudo as all of these locations have directories and files not beloning to your user.

how would I have it look in all my files instead of the current directory

altered it :) @steeldriver 's comment will likely be the answer to what is asked.
